# Macro is not reading the correct value from a cell which contains a math formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a Excel Workbook that is a template and is populated using macros. 
In a several cells, I have a formula `=abs(sum(H20:P20))`.

In my macro, I am trying to hide the row based on the value in that cell.

I reference those cells from a named range using an offset that does not change and then iterate over 8 lines to decide whether to hide them or not.

I have tried various 'Evaluate' and 'Calculate' functions on the cells in question thinking that maybe it was not evaluating the formula in the cell.

```
For s = 1 To 8
  If Worksheets(sheet1).Range("Spend").Offset(s, 15).Value = 0 Then 
    Worksheets(sheet1).Range("Spend").Offset(s, 15).EntireRow.Hidden = True
  End If
Next s
```

I expect it to hide several of the rows but it does not do anything. After all macros are done in the file; and the rows have not been hidden, I run that same macro again. On this second run, it hides the rows correctly.

Comment: "After all macros are done in the file" - what are the other macros doing?  There doesn't seem to be any problem with the code you posted, so something else is going on...

Comment: Have you checked the value of that cell down to the nth decimal?  It may be that the cell is formatted with no decimals but the value very much has decimals.  Something to check anyway.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code and seeing what the line Worksheets(sheet1).Range("Spend").Offset(s, 15).Value shows when you think it should hide it?